# How to compare two functions which satisfy some conditions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

$f(x),g(x)$ are defined on $[-1,1]$, $f'(0),g'(0)$ exist, $f(0)=g(0)$, and $f(x)\ge g(x)$ holds for an open interval containing $0$. Then which of the following is correct:

I, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same tangent line at $(0,0)$;

II, $f'(0)\ge g'(0)$;

III, $g''(0)$ exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}x\ge\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}x$$

Answer (score 2):

II may be correct.

say we consider a function $ h(x)= f(x)- g(x) $

differentiating w.r.t x , we would get $h'(x) = f'(x) - g'(x) $

your $f(x) $>= $ g(x)$ <=> $ f'(x) >= g'(x) $

and $ f'(0) >= g'(0) $

Comment: Your $\;f(x)\ge g(x)\iff f'(x)\ge g'(x)\;$ is wrong. For example, in $\;[-1,0]\;$ , we have that $$\;f(x)>g(x)\;,\;\;f(x)=4\;,\;\;g(x)=-x^2\;,\;\;\text{yet}\;\;f'(x)\le g'(x)\ldots$$

Comment: i am using the fact that h(x) is an increasing function.

Comment: Also in my example $\;h(x):=f(x)-g(x)\;$ is increasing, yet it is *not* true that $\;h'(x)\ge 0\;$ ...